# Given two states which are close in trace distance, are there purifications of these states which are equally close?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator, quantum-states

Given a pair of state $\rho_A$ and $\sigma_A$ such that they are close in trace distance i.e.

$$|\rho_A - \sigma_A| \leq \epsilon,$$

can one find purifications of these states which are also $\epsilon$ close in trace distance i.e.

$$|\phi_{AA'} - \psi_{AA'}| \leq \epsilon$$

We are free here to take our pick over all unitaries on the $A'$ subsystem to help achieve the bound. And if not $\epsilon$, can we say anything non-trivial about the distance between the best possible purifications?

Comment: Have you checked Uhlmann's theorem?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch thank you! I had forgotten about it. It answers my question perfectly - if you wish to put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at [Uhlmann's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.or/wiki/Fidelity_of_quantum_states#Uhlmann's_theorem): It is not about the trace distance, but a different distance measure, the *fidelity*, and states that the fidelity of two mixed states is equal to the maximum fidelity of their purifications - that is, their "fidelity distance" is the smallest "fidelity distance" over all purifications. (In addition, it is possible to [relate fidelity and trace distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidelity_of_quantum_states#Relationship_to_trace_distance), so that way you can also get a relation for the latter.)